# NullPointerException when calling variable from another class

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I am a QA Engineer writing a test script. I am attempting to set a URL string variable that is equal to the URL of the current page in a method and call the method containing the variable in a test method.

*Edit****
Originally I thought this was an issue with the variable itself but this is not the case. I have adjusted my question to better represent the problem

When I initiate and define the URL variable in the same class and method as the test it works fine

```
public void RFPsCreatedStatusTest(){
    RequestsataGlance.RFPinProgressbtnclick();
    RequestsataGlance.CreatedClick();
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
   System.out.println(url);
Assert.assertTrue(url.contains("url.com"), "Incorrect Page, SR list call status does not match status selected ");
```

But when I create and call the public void() {}  URL method [createdassertion]separately from outside of the test method and class it doesn't work. Thoughts?

```
 @Test
        public void RFPsCreatedStatusTest(){
            RequestsataGlance.RFPinProgressbtnclick();
            RequestsataGlance.CreatedClick();
            RequestsataGlance.Createdassertion();


        }`
```

Comment: I've edited the question to better reflect the problem

Answer (score 2):

the line below is useless, as you will redefine url variable in next statement

```
url = new String();
```

after the line

```
url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

url will contain the browser url, then why should it contain the string "[expected result]"? of course it will not, as it will contain an URL

**EDIT 1**

from definition

```
assertTrue(java.lang.String message, boolean condition)
```

so use it as below

```
Assert.assertTrue("Incorrect Page, SR list call status does not match status selected ", url.contains("whatever.com"));
```

Comment: My apologies for the confusion I know that it will return whatever the URL is but since there wasn't one I just put [expected condition] as poor choice for a placeholder.

Comment: then, maybe the `driver.getCurrentUrl();` statement does not return anything, that is it returns null and so you can't use the url variable

Comment: Good thought, I defined the URL to be "123" , the assertion should have failed but instead I still got the exception.

Comment: @Lamar, I updated my answer, did you try it again? You should use the assert differently as I wrote

Comment: I double checked  the assert statement and it is boolean,  string:  not string, boolean.  I realized I left out an important piece and forgive as I am just getting used to SO I am calling that Method into a test method in another class, see my updated post

Comment: see the aboveabove...

Answer (score 1):

The only way anything can be null in your code is if

```
driver.getCurrentUrl()
```

returns null.
After all, you wrote a Test and found a problem. Just fix it! ;-)

Btw.: your code will be much more easy to read if you simply write:

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

Comment: Added some additional detail to the original post